# Does Exp:resso Store have Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking ability built in?

Tags: expresso-store

Does Exp:resso Store have out of the box support for Google analytics ecommerce tracking (like Magento)?

More details: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce

Answer (score 1):

Yup. The full documentation is avilabe at https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/settings_conversion_tracking.html